# “Had to" “have to" “has to" “will have to" uses?

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence grammatically correct ?

- Sorry dad i wasn't able to pick up your phone as i was busy and **had to complete** my work.

Correct to use present tense after had to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, what follows *had to* is not the present of the verb, but the bare infinitive. In fact, it would not change for the third person singular too.

> She had to finish lunch, before going with her friends at the park.

Yes, the sentence is correct, in the same the following sentence is correct.

> She will have to finish lunch, before coming with us at the park.

Answer (score 1):

Here **have to** is a modal verb and it means **something that you have to do**.

> I have to complete my work.
>   I had to complete my work

Yes the sentence is correct.